# How to create outputs with different number of decimals, depending on user's input (that can be a number from 1 to 3)?

Tags: java, sum, decimal, mean, decimalformat

I'm attending a Java course for beginners and I have this exercise to do:

- There are 5 students admitted to take an exam at college
- Create showInputDialog for each student's grade
- Create also showInputDialog to ask user to enter a number from 1 to 3 which represents the number of decimal numbers to display the mean of the 5 student's grades (for example: if user writes "2" he will get a mean like this XX,XX)
- If the mean of the 5 grades is higher than 25, the program must display a window to the user that says "mean result passing"

I have done everything but I'm stuck at the point where I have to create the output to show the mean with the amount of decimal numbers choose by the user.

How can I create outputs with different number of decimals, depending on user's input (that can be a number from 1 to 3)?

I show you my code:

```
package module2;

import java.text.DecimalFormat;

import javax.swing.JOptionPane;

public class GradeMean2 {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        
        String gradeStudent1, gradeStudent2, gradeStudent3, gradeStudent4, gradeStudent5;
        int valGradeStudent1, valGradeStudent2, valGradeStudent3, valGradeStudent4, valGradeStudent5, sum;
        double mean;
        String mean1Decimal, mean2Decimals, mean3Decimals;
        String decimalNumber;
        double valDecimalNumber;
        String output;
        
        DecimalFormat oneNumber = new DecimalFormat("0.0");
        DecimalFormat twoNumbers = new DecimalFormat("0.00");
        DecimalFormat threeNumbers = new DecimalFormat("0.000");
        
        gradeStudent1 = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Insert grade student 1");
        valGradeStudent1 = Integer.parseInt(gradeStudent1);
        
        gradeStudent2 = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Insert grade student 2");
        valGradeStudent2 = Integer.parseInt(gradeStudent2);
        
        gradeStudent3 = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Insert grade student 3");
        valGradeStudent3 = Integer.parseInt(gradeStudent3);
        
        gradeStudent4 = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Insert grade student 4");
        valGradeStudent4 = Integer.parseInt(gradeStudent4);

        gradeStudent5 = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Insert grade student 5");
        valGradeStudent5 = Integer.parseInt(gradeStudent5);
        
        decimalNumber = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Insert number of decimals of mean");
        valDecimalNumber = Integer.parseInt(decimalNumber);
        
        output = "Grades:" + "\ngrade student 1 = " +gradeStudent1 +"\ngrade student 2 = " +gradeStudent2 +"\ngrade student 3 = " +gradeStudent3 +"\ngrade student 4 = " +gradeStudent4 +"\ngrade student 5 = " +gradeStudent5  +"\n\n";

        sum = valGradeStudent1 + valGradeStudent2 + valGradeStudent3 + valGradeStudent4 + valGradeStudent5;
        mean = (double)sum/5;

        mean1Decimal = oneNumber.format(media);
        mean2Decimals = twoNumbers.format(media);
        mean3Decimals = threeNumbers.format(media);

        if(media >= 25)
            output = output + "\nMean result passing";
        
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, output);
        System.exit(0);
```

Comment: You have presented your assignment, but you have not described your problem or asked a question. Just posting your homework is not sufficient.

Comment: Hello Mark, I asked in the main question title: "how to create outputs with different number of decimals, depending on user's input (that can be a number from 1 to 3)?"... maybe I have to repeat the question in the text below?

Comment: Now I added the question in bold, I hope it's ok now. Thank you.

Comment: I have removed the excessive use of bold, as that actually hurts readability. Thanks for adding a question, but to be honest, it is not clear to me what you want/need to achieve.

Comment: When you have repetitive lines of code, think loops and/or arrays